# A part of horizontal list view is not on a base line

Tags: flutter

A part of a horizontal scroll list is not on a base line, here is `Icefields, Alberta` is aligned to the top of sized box. How to fix it? The whole list view should be on the same horizontal level.

[image]

```
SizedBox(
width: double.maxFinite,
height: 50,
    child: ListView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      children: [
        const Icon(...),
        const SizedBox(...),
        AppText(
          text: detail.place.location,
          color: AppColors.textColor1,
        ),
        const SizedBox(...),
        Row(
          children: [
            Wrap(
              children: List.generate(5, (index) {
                return Icon(...);
              }),
            ),
            const SizedBox(...),
            AppText(
              text:
                  detail.place.stars.toString() + '.0',
              color: AppColors.textColor2,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution is to put the location `AppText` within the `Row`:

```
Row(
    children: [
      AppText(
        text: detail.place.location,
        color: AppColors.textColor1,
      ),
      Wrap(
        children: List.generate(5, (index) {
          return Icon(...);
        }),
      ),
      const SizedBox(...),
      AppText(
        text:
            detail.place.stars.toString() + '.0',
        color: AppColors.textColor2,
      ),
    ],
)
```

This way all widgets in the `Row` are aligned the same.

Comment: this solution is better

Comment: Actually all the widgets could be in a `Row`, instead of a horizontal `ListView`. Why do you need it, is it possible that the contents don't fit horizontally?

Comment: those all wigget makes horizontal overflowing when location takes more space and that is why they are in the ListView

Answer (score 1):

Wrap `AppText` with `Center` widget.

```dart
  ....
  Center(
    child: AppText(
      text: detail.place.location,
      color: AppColors.textColor1,
    ),
  ),
 ....
```

Comment: Default alignment is start for `children`.  You can also use `Align` widget for custom alignment.